# Access API endpoints in MEANjs from server controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mean-stack, meanjs

so i have this problem i am working on *'following'* feature in my application. What's important, i have two models:

`Follows` and `Notifications`

When I hit follow button in front-end I run function from `follow.client.controller.js` which POSTs to API endpoint `/api/follows` which corresponds to `follow.server.controller.js` and then update action on `Follows` model is performed - easy. AFAIK thats how it works (and it works for me).

But in `follows.server.controller.js` I want also invoke post to API endpoint at `/api/notifications` which corresponds to `notifications.server.controller.js` but I can't find a proper way to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

I don't want another call from front-end to add notification because it should be automatic = if user starts following someone, information is saved in both models at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add middleware in your server route.

```
app.route('/api/follows')
    .post(notification.firstFunction, follows.secondFunction);
```

And now add 2 methods in your contollers. First makes the call to db and add's some result's data to request object which will be forwarded to second method.

```
exports.firstFunction= function(req, res, next) {

    Notification.doSometing({
        }).exec(function(err, result) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            req.yourValueToPassForward = result
            next(); // <-- important
        });

};

exports.secondFunction= function(req, res) {
    //...
};
```

Or you can make few database calls in one api method, joining this calls with promises. Example:

```
var promise = Meetups.find({ tags: 'javascript' }).select('_id').exec();
promise.then(function (meetups) {
  var ids = meetups.map(function (m) {
    return m._id;
  });
  return People.find({ meetups: { $in: ids }).exec();
}).then(function (people) {
  if (people.length &lt; 10000) {
    throw new Error('Too few people!!!');
  } else {
    throw new Error('Still need more people!!!');
  }
}).then(null, function (err) {
  assert.ok(err instanceof Error);
});
```

Comment: Thank you Mike. First solution is the one I needed, I'm still new to MEANjs so can you tell me what is source of this kind of knowledge? Do you have some books/articles about MEANjs you can recommend or this is just docs of express/node? (Of course i'm not asking you to crawl google, just want to know if you have some favs)

Comment: There is no good knowledge base for MEAN stack. You must recognize which parts of code belongs to which technology. Backend controllers and models are using Mongoosejs library that provides methods for communication with mongoDB and mongoose models. (http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html)  Other files are mostly Express configration files ( e.g. rountings) for which u can find documentation here: http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: You can also have angular make two http requests based on the success of the first one, but the first option here is better