# How to call delete from other class MEAN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I can't figure out how I delete data in another MongoDB scheme when I create.

I'm running on mean.js stack.

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  var sign = new Sign(req.body);

  sign.save(function(err) {

    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      sign.timesheets.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log(entry._id);
      });

      res.jsonp(sign);
    }
  });
};
```

Here I make a call to create a sign. Sign includes some strings and an array 'timesheets' with timesheet objects.

I also got a scheme for timesheets, I want to delete all timesheets objects that are included in my sign from timesheets scheme.

Here is my timesheets delete controller:

```
exports.delete = function(req, res) {
  var timesheet = req.timesheet;

  timesheet.remove(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
      });
    } else {
      res.jsonp(timesheet);
    }
  });
};
```

How do I call this from min sign controller, for each timesheet in sign?

**Edit**:

Route:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    var sign = require('../../app/controllers/sign.server.controller');
    var timesheets = require('../../app/controllers/timesheets.server.controller');


    app.route('/sign')
      .post(sign.create, timesheets.deleteAll);

    delete all

    exports.deleteAll = function(req, res) {
      var timesheet = req.timesheet;
      timesheet.timesheets._id.forEach(function(entry) {
        entry.remove(function(err) {
          console.log(entry);
          if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
              message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
          } else {
            res.jsonp(entry);
          }
        });
      });
    };
```

It runs and I can see id in the console, but it doesn't delete anything.

Comment: If you are accessing this controllers throu API, try Mike's solution under my question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138498/access-api-endpoints-in-meanjs-from-server-controller

Comment: @karolkochan done that now put it dosen't delete the timesheets :/

Comment: I think your code `entry.remove(...)` in `deleteAll` function doesn't know that entry reffers to yours Timesheet model. So you need to run something like `Timesheed.remove( { _id: { $in: your_array } }, false );` (refferring to mongo docs) where `your_array` in this case is `timesheet.timesheets`

Comment: @karolkochan  yea you are right it looks like this now 
http://pastebin.com/Nd21H2Qq
but crash if it has more then one timesheet, think it is cause res.jsonp(timesheet),  how do i change this to res after for each is done ? :)

Comment: You can try this:
http://pastebin.com/DgKS5zTD 
or this:
http://pastebin.com/9j9VigYK
Simply add `index` variable and check for last element to return response object.

Answer (score 0):

If you've implemented this as an array of TimesheetSchema documents inside each SignSchema document, then deleting the parent document would take everything that's part of it with it.

If you stored it as an array of ids referencing a document in another collection, then you'd have to go through those one by one and remove them as well. But I think it's better to go with the first approach if you don't need to do anything fancy. This was you can handle the removal easily, and it makes better sense semantically and performance-wise to retrieve everything you need to handle a "sign" in one go.